# Loading a framed page with specific pages in each frame

Tags: html, frames

I'm trying to create a link to a page with frames. The page has 2 frames - left side for menu and right side for content.

Linking to the URL brings up the index, but I want a specific sub-page on the site.

Is there any way to link to the sub-page while still keeping the format of the frames?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set your link HREF value to the specific "sub-page" URL and set the TARGET property to the specific frame you want it to display within.